# javadoc.zip for libGoogleAnalytics.jar in android

Tags: android, google-analytics, javadoc

I'm trying to extend the tracking via google analytic on my android app. Currently I'm trying to send custom variables. But it seams that I'm missing the java docs for the library, can someone please send me the javadoc.zip. Also how do I send a custom variable with a `trackPageView` or `trackEvent` method(call). I seams that I can't specify in witch method(call) I'll be using the custom variable.
For example I need to call the `trackEvent` on a button click and also send a custom var with it, or I need to call the `trackPageView` and send a custom war with this method.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download GoogleAnalytics Android SDK 2.0 beta 3 from https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/resources.It has javadocs.zip.
To send custom Variables in Google Analytics Android ,you can use this api call

EasyTracker.getTracker().trackView("My Custom Variable:"+ x); This Value will be visible in Screen Views of Google Analytcs Dashboard

Comment: I'm truing to use the old analytic tool, the one for 1.5.1 (legacy) and this one is missing the documentation

Answer (score 1):

The `trackEvent` is for events, and the `trackPageView` is for pageviews.

```
EasyTracker.getTracker().trackEvent("MainPage", "Info buttonclick", "date today", (long) 1);
```

And pageviews

```
EasyTracker.getTracker().trackView("MainPage");
```

see: [Analytics events](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/events) and [pageviews](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/screens)